# password protected application in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, web.xml

I am developing a web application using(JSP + Servlet), and I have used `Tomcat 7.0.33` as a `web container`.

So my requirement is that each application in tomcat will be `password` protected like the `manager application` in tomcat is protected.

So far I have done following:

**server.xml**

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
```

**tomcat-users.xml**

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="role1" />

    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="role1,tomcat,manager-gui"/>
    <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**web.xml**

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>role1</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>webappname</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>role1</role-name>
    <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
<realm-name>webappname</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

It works fine when anyone opens the application by application path(it asks for username & password, and application accepts either of the `role1` or `tomcat` for authentication).

But the Issue is that suppose if I login as a user `tomcat` who has got all roles, and when the manager screen is shown which lists all the application deployed on the server, then if I try to open `mywebapplication` then it again asks for username and password.

My question is that if I have assigned all the `roles` to the user `tomcat` then why it asks for password if I have login as `tomcat`? is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
<realm-name>webappname</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Basic Auth credentials are organized in "Security Realms". If you give all your apps different Realm-Names, the browser will prompt for each. Try using the same name for all of them (if that is what you want).