# How Do I password protect an application on Tomcat Application Manager?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have deployed a war file inside a folder in the Tomcat **webapps** folder and the manager page is password protected. But I also want to password protect my application other than the Login system which it has of its own. I tried doing what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609646/password-protected-application-in-tomcat).

But There has been no luck, when I do what it is mentioned there even the tomcat page i.e, *localhost:8080* is also not accessible as it gives a not found error whereas I am able to access *localhost:8080/manager/html* page with the credentials and when I click on the Application I want to access it still doesn't ask for credentials but directly opens the web application.

Comment: Why do you want two password protection layers?

Comment: @Henry Just a requirement TBH.